# How to make a return type mixed and self?

Tags: php, phpstorm

```php
class Foo 
{
    final public function get(string $path): mixed
    {
        // return mixed or self type;
    }

    final public function otherMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

In this example, the return value can be of any type, incl. object of oneself (`static`).

How to ensure that the editor PhpStorm can provide hints as:

```php
$obj->get('path.to.any.data')->otherMethod();
```

Currently, due to the type, the mixed editor cannot provide a hint.

Comment: Yes, the `mixed` type causes a problem here. You could try `mixed | Foo`, but that will generate an error: _"Fatal error: Type mixed can only be used as a standalone type"_, which makes perfectly sense. I don't think there's a solution for this, but I don't use PHPStorm.... so... anybody?

Comment: Well .. if it's `mixed` (which means "any" -- an `int`, `string` or even `null`) .. then how do you expect `get('path.to.any.data')->` to actually work (as it will generate PHP runtime error on non object)? P.S. It sounds to me like you have provided an overly simplified code. How it the actual `get()` method works? Does it return different type base don the parameter value etc?

Answer (score 0):

PHPStorm gives the ability to add meta files to the project, which can be used to tell PHPStorm which return type to expect based on a method argument value.

However, that may not be suitable for pure dynamic paths / values.

See: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/ide-advanced-metadata.html

There are a lot of possibilites which can be used. One basic example to get a feeling (Disclaimer: not tested):

```php
<?php

// FILENAME: ./.phpstorm.meta.php

/**
 * Extend PhpStorms code completion capabilities by providing a meta file
 *
 * @link https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/ide-advanced-metadata.html
 */

namespace PHPSTORM_META {

    expectedArguments(
        \Vendor\Namespace\Foo::get(),
        0,
        'path.to.any.data',
        'path.to.some.class',
    );
    override(Vendor\Namespace\Foo::get(), map([
        'path.to.any.data' => 1234123,
        'path.to.some.class' => \Vendor\Namespace\SomeClassOrInterface::class,
    ]));

}
```

Note: Having a  `get()` method retrieving any kind of data or the class itselfs seems kind of a messy interface for me. In my eyes the method should only return some values or nothing (null) and avoiding further nesting changes which outside code needs to handle.